# MVC 300K row data table from excel into SQL using User-defined Table Types - Operand type clash

Tags: sql, vb.net, model-view-controller

I am wanting to import 300K + rows from excel (heat monitoring data) into MsSQL DB via MVC and a User-defined Table Type.

I have chosen to use a Table Type and a stored procedure as I don't want to cycle through the data and create dynamic SQL to upload 300K records as that would take an age to process (tried it!).

The process I am using is:

- Import the data from MVC page to controller using JSON
- Pass the InputStream into GetDataFromCSVFile fuction
- Create DataTable and populate with stream
- Create New SqlParameter with the data type and the table
- I then pass the data table to msSql server using a stored procedure.

Full Code.

```
Public Async Function DataImport(ByVal DataImports As HttpPostedFileBase) As Task(Of ActionResult)

            If DataImports Is Nothing Then Return Json(New With {Key .Status = 0, Key .Message = "No File Selected"})

                
             Try
                Dim fileData = GetDataFromCSVFile(DataImports.InputStream)
                Dim dtManualHeatData = fileData.ToArray()

                Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()
                table.Columns.Add("ManualHeatDataId", GetType(String))
                table.Columns.Add("DateAndTime", GetType(Date))
                table.Columns.Add("Pulse", GetType(Integer))

                For Each Line As Object In dtManualHeatData
                    Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
                    row("ManualHeatDataId") = Line.ManualHeatDataId
                    row("DateAndTime") = Line.DateAndTime
                    row("Pulse") = Line.Pulse
                    table.Rows.Add(row)
                Next
                Dim tblManualHeatData = New SqlParameter("myManualHeatDatas", SqlDbType.Structured) With {.TypeName = "dbo.ManualHeatDatasType",
                                                                                                            .Value = table
                                                                                                        }
                Dim SQL As String = "EXEC dbo.ImportManualHeatData @myManualHeatDatas"
                Await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(SQL, tblManualHeatData)
                Return Json(New With {Key .Status = 1, Key .Message = "File Imported Successfully "})
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Json(New With {Key .Status = 0, Key .Message = ex.Message})
            End Try
End Function
Private Function GetDataFromCSVFile(ByVal stream As Stream) As List(Of ManualHeatData)
        Dim ManualHeatList = New List(Of ManualHeatData)()
        Try
            Using reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)
                Dim dataset = reader.AsDataSet(New ExcelDataSetConfiguration() With {
                                    .ConfigureDataTable = Function(__) New ExcelDataTableConfiguration() With {
                                    .UseHeaderRow = True,
                                    .ReadHeaderRow = Function(rowReader)
                                                         rowReader.Read()
                                                         rowReader.Read()
                                                         rowReader.Read()
                                                         rowReader.Read()
                                                         rowReader.Read()
                                                         rowReader.Read()
                                                     End Function}})

                If dataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim dataTable = dataset.Tables(0)
                    Dim Count As Long = 0
                    For Each objDataRow As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
                        Count = +1
                        If objDataRow.ItemArray.All(Function(x) String.IsNullOrEmpty(x?.ToString())) Then Continue For
                        ManualHeatList.Add(New ManualHeatData() With {
                            .ManualHeatDataId = Count,
                            .DateAndTime = objDataRow("Date").ToString(),
                            .Pulse = objDataRow("Pulses (Pulses)").ToString()
                        })
                    Next
                End If
            End Using

        Catch Ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try

        Return ManualHeatList
End Function
```

That whole process above until Await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync takes around 15 seconds which is fine for my needs. The issue is that I am getting the following error when the db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync is run.

> Operand type clash: ManualHeatDatasType is incompatible with nvarchar

I have been able to go into the SQL server and look at the SQL which has been passed to it by the above code but not excecated using the event logger. When I look at this SQL statement its only 3711 rows long and when I excite it using SSMS, it adds rows to the required table correctly. Example below of the SQL statement as seen in event logger but not executed.

```
declare @p3 dbo.ManualHeatDatasType
insert into @p3 values(N'1','2020-10-14 12:31:15',0)
insert into @p3 values(N'1','2020-10-14 12:31:25',1)
insert into @p3 values(N'1','2020-10-14 12:31:35',0)
..loads more rows!...
insert into @p3 values(N'1','2020-10-14 22:48:45',0)
insert into @p3 values(N'1','2020-10-14 22:48:55',0)
insert into @p3 values(N'1','2020-10-14 22:49:05',0)
insert into @p3 values(N'1','2020-10-14 22:49:15',0)
insert into @p3 values(N'1','2020-10-14 22:49:25',0)
insert into @p3 values(N'1','2020-10-14 22:49:35',0)

exec sp_executesql N'EXEC dbo.ImportManualHeatData @myManualHeatDatas',N'@myManualHeatDatas [dbo].[ManualHeatDatasType] READONLY',@myManualHeatDatas=@p3
```

If I repeat the test several times it always ends up stopping at 3711 rows passed to SQL and not run. So I was thinking that the issue is related to the data on just after 3711 or 22:49:35 in the datatable/stream.

But all the data around this point is clean and exactly the same as the data before it.

If anyone has any pointers or feedback on where things are going wrong please let me know.
Cheers,
Richard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the solution!

Rather than using a stored procedure, table type and mapping the data table to the type I have found **SqlBulkCopy**!!!

After creating the table in the original question above I am able to use the SqlBulkCopy as below to push the whole datatable into the SQL server and the whole process of reading and importing into SQL for 300k rows from excel takes around 5 seconds!! mind blowing!!

```
            Using dbcontext As ApplicationDbContext = New ApplicationDbContext()
                Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(DbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString)
                sqlCon.Open()
                Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(sqlCon)
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = Data_Base + ".dbo.ManualHeatDatas"
                    Try
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                    Finally
                        table.Dispose()
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for returning with your solution. I just have to clarify that CSV is not an excel file, it's a text file. They are very different. Bulk Copy in fact cannot import excel files, and excel files are very unreliable for data transfer

Comment: Sorry yes your right to clarify, I missed that the function was called GetDataFromCSVFile, that was a copy past fail! The document I am importing is infect as .xlsx file and I do more validation on this before importing to ensure I have the correct data/format etc..